# Changing Time column of HtmlLayout to use date format in lg4j2.xml

Tags: log4j2

I am using HTMLLayout for logging using lg4j2.xml

I want to change the default Time column that comes with HTMLLayout.
To show something like this 2019-05-16 16:45:06,032

I know it can be done with conversion pattern, 
But i was unable to find a sample.
I found many examples of extending HTMLLayout  class-  I don't want to do this.

this is the HTMLLayout  portion in my lg4j2.xml:

```
    <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/printer_log.html"  filePattern="${basePath}/printer_log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.html">
        <HTMLLayout charset="UTF-8" title="Printer Logs" locationInfo="true" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

Comment: The conversion pattern is used with a Pattern layout not HTML layout. You could probably generate HTML by using the Pattern layout and thereby take advantage of the conversion pattern, but I don't see anything in the log4j2 manual that would indicate HTML layout can be customized in the way you want.

Comment: BTW, any particular reason that you do not want to extend `HTMLLayout` class ?

Comment: because its a code change vs configuration change (configuration change is much easier for me to push to our production system)

Comment: Without code change, it seems not possible. Calculation logic for time shown in `HTMLLayout` is fixed in source code https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/HtmlLayout.java#L152